# Unable to fetch SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity

I'm trying to get familiar with using SharedPreferences, by building a simple test app where I store and retrieve user preferences by using a class that extends 'PreferenceActivity'.

The problem is that every time I shut down the app and start it again I'm unable to load the SharedPreferences values that I earlier selected.

In the MainActivity's onCreate method I am first calling a method 'loadPreferences', then creating an ImageView and a button. 
I assigned onclick listener to the button that creates and starts a new intent.

```
...onClick(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyPrefsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In MyPrefsActivity class I have a ListPreference that has a 'Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener'.

```
... {
    @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            imageNumber = Integer.parseInt(newValue.toString());
            return true;
        }
    };
```

Upon return from MyPrefsActivity to MainActivity in the 'onResume':

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    savePreferences();
    loadPreferences();
}

private void savePreferences(){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("imageNumber", MyPrefsActivity.imageNumber);
    editor.apply();
}

private void loadPreferences (){
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        int imageNumb = prefs.getInt("imageNumber", 0);                                                       
        switch (imageNumb){
            case 0:
                imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.image1);
                break;
            case 1:
                imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.image2);
                break;
            case 2:
                imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.image3);
                break;
            default:
                imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.image4);
        }
}
```

When 'loadPreferences' is called for the first time upon startup, 'imageNumb' allways has a value 0, instaed of the value that I assigned to on previous run in method 'savePreferences'.

I noticed that after startup when I enter 'MyPreferencesAction' for the first time and open the ListPreferences, the checkbox that I selected on the last run is already selected for me. It seems like my selection is saved but when I try to load SharedPreferences am I messing up something???

Answer (score 1):

You have to save your preferences in `onPause` event. Right now you are saving it in `onResume` when values you want are no longer there.

```
@Override
protected void onPause(){
   super.onPause();
   savePreferences();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    loadPreferences();
}
```

There is another issue with your code. You are saving preferences in `MainActivity`, but you are changing them in `MyPrefsActivity`. That will not work. You have to save changes to the preferences in `MyPrefsActivity`, use above load/save pattern in there too. If you don't have any preference changes happening in `MainActivity`, you can safely omit calling `savePreferences` from it.

Depending on `MyPrefsActivity` declaration calling `MyPrefsActivity.imageNumber` from `MainActivity` may not be safe, you will have to change that code too. Like I said, most likely you don't need it at all in `MainActivity` (if you saving are only preferences values that are set in `MyPrefsActivity`) and that should be part of `MyPrefsActivity`.

Also `Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener` is probably redundant since it's main usage is to be invoked when the value of this Preference has been changed by the user and is about to be set and/or persisted. This gives the client a chance to prevent setting and/or persisting the value.

Comment: I would go as far as to save in onPause. The possibility exists where you would exit the App, and start the App again before onStop starts. You would lose your saved preferences in this case. Infact, this is quite likely to happen.

Comment: Oh now see, I think... So 'onResume' is allso called upon on the startup so the method 'savePreferences' sets the SharedPreference(key) value to 0 on startup. Did i understand this correctly?

I did as you adviced and now i have only method 'loadPreferences' in 'onResume' and in 'onStop' i have method 'savePreferences'.But now when I change the preferences and push the back button. The image is change is not instant, but instead I have to leave the screen one more time and return to get the right image to show up. How should should I fix this?

Comment: Thank you for you example 'Dalija Prasnikar'. But there was an issue I got with that code. The image change was not instant, but instead I had to leave the screen 1 more time and return to get the image to update.
I came up with a workaround. I initialize the (static int variable) MyPreferenceActivity.imageNumber with the SharedPreferences(key) value in MainActivitys 'onCreate' method and now on onResume I call both methods 'savePreferences' and 'loadPreferences'... What am I doing wrong? This code feels so dirty...

Comment: @Knossos You are right, `onPause` is better place, even though official Android documentation suggests using `onStop`, so I have updated answer accordingly.

Comment: I have updated answer, you have other issues in your code, I somehow failed to realize that before.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I posted a followup question. Could you please have a look at.

Answer (score 0):

I realized there was a lot of needless complexity in my code. So I got completely rid of the method savePreferences(). Instead i simplified the PreferenceChangeListeners method onPreferenceChange(...):
This seems to me to be the most simplest way to update SharedPreferences when using PreferenceActivity.

```
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {                
            preference.getEditor().
            putInt("imageNumber", Integer.parseInt(newValue.toString())).apply();
            return true;
        }
```

Now I save the SharedPreferences manually, only when 'onPreferenceChange' is called. Not on 'onResume', 'onStop', 'onRestart' or on 'onPause'.

Please inform me if this is a bad way to change SharedPreferences.

Quoting Dalija Prasnikar: "reference.OnPreferenceChangeListener is probably redundant since it's main usage is to be invoked when the value of this Preference has been changed by the user and is about to be set and/or persisted. This gives the client a chance to prevent setting and/or persisting the value."

If you understood you correctly Dalija, there is a 'onPreferenceChange(...)' like method that does the job but does not have a boolean return value but void? I was not able to find any examples, could you please show or point to an examle?